# How to delete my flag?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged a question without understanding it's correct meaning.

Is it possible to delete/remove if once I flagged incorrectly for a question ?

Comment: No, it's not possible. However you can post a comment describing that you flagged it mistakenly.

Comment: @Danatela Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following information from [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) is helpful:

> **Is there any way to remove flags?**
>  
> There is often no need, as offensive
>   and spam flags expire after 48 hours if the thresholds aren't reached.
>   
> Rolling back a post to a previous state will revert to the number of
>   offensive flags from that particular revision. This allows the OP (or
>   someone else with edit rights) to rollback a post that someone else
>   made offensive in a later revision. However as a general user, once
>   you mark a post as offensive, you cannot take it back.